# Using Actionbar_sherlock to display searchview on gingerbread

Tags: android, mono, actionbarsherlock

I want to use the searchview in gingerbread (like how Whatsapp does it).
I am using ActionBar_Sherlock 4.2.0, but for some reason i can't find the Searchview, while it should be supported (I can find the class files)

ActionBar_Sherlock.widget only has ShareActionProvider. I have no idea why this isn't working.
Can somebody help me out?

Thanks

Comment: what is your targetSDK?

Comment: Android 2.3 API level 10, but searchview should be available for api level 8+

Comment: try targeting higher sdk, while maintaining minSdk as gingerbread or lower, see if it helps

Comment: I'm targeting API level 17 with minSdk = 10 but I still can't find SearchView.